# How to expose Django Rest APIView fields to swagger?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have something like this:

```py
class MyCustomView(APIView):
    serializer_class = serializers.MyCustomSerializer

    def post(self, request):
        #my custom logic here, working on multiple tables, etc
```

But the serialization fields do not show up in swagger or default Django rest HTML view. How can I make it so it does?

**Edit**

I see it works in browseable API with latest Django Rest, but not in swagger. I'm using `drf_yasg`. Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: *"or default Django rest HTML..."* In newer versions of DRF, `serializer_class` is rendered in *Browsable API*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out you can force serializer for swagger like this:

```py
   ...
   @swagger_auto_schema(request_body=SomeSerializer)
   def post():
      pass
   ...
```